# storing multiple objects in XML file

Tags: java, xml, file, object

I have a simple java program to write an object to a xml file, my problem is that no matter how I do it, I can just store 1 object in the xml file.
my code goes as follows

```
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAttribute ;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement ;
    import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement ;

    @XmlRootElement
    public class Product {

        String Name;
        int Price;

        @XmlElement
        public void setName(String Name) {
            this.Name = Name;
        }

        @XmlElement
        public void setPrice(int price) {
            this.price = price;
        }
    }
import xml.Product;
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

    public class XML {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Product product=new Product();
            product.setName("Hamburger");
            product.setPrice(10);

            try{
                //File file = new File("C:\\file.xml");
                JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Product.class);
                Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

                // output pretty printed
                jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(product, file);
                jaxbMarshaller.marshal(product, System.out);
            }catch(JAXBException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 

        }
        }
```

but even if I instance 2 products, I get just one object in my XML file(which is written correctly)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Product>
     <Name>Hamburger</Name>
     <price>10</price>
</Product>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by using a List of Product for example

[image: Marshalling a list of products]

**Here is Product.java refactored**:

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "product")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product {
    private String Name;
    private int price;

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setName(String Name) {
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

Now **create a Products entity that will have a field of type List**

```
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement(name = "products")
@XmlAccessorType (XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Products {
    @XmlElement(name = "product")
    private List<Product> products = null;

    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }

    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }
}
```

And finally **a demo:**

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class ProductsDump {
    static Products products = new Products();
    static
    {
        products.setProducts(new ArrayList<>()); 
        Product prod1 = new Product();
        prod1.setName("Hamburger");
        prod1.setPrice(10);
        Product prod2 = new Product();
        prod2.setName("Bretzel");
        prod2.setPrice(5);
        products.getProducts().add(prod1);
        products.getProducts().add(prod2);
    }
    private static void marshalingExample() throws JAXBException
    {
        JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Products.class);
        Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

        jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);

        //Marshal the products list in console
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(products, System.out);

        //Marshal the products list in file
        jaxbMarshaller.marshal(products, new File("c:/products.xml"));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        marshalingExample();
    }
}
```

Comment: ahh thanks man! I tried it and it worked! it had never occurred to me to put it in a List! I'm new to XML files in general, so I'm a bit lost right now

Comment: thanks man! This is really the best place to find advices, and get answers!

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, this is kind of like asking if it's plugged in, but your example only has thing.  You need a list of some sort.  Add the products to the list and then serialize the list.

Also take a look at XStream, you can get it to do the xml bits for you and you won't have to deal with the javax stuff.  It'll serialize to and from XML for you.

Comment: so, I should add the object to a List<Product> and then write each object inside the list that to the xml file?